# Horizontal scroll view in phonegap

Tags: android, css, html, cordova

In my phonegap app i want to implement horizontal scroll view. My html code

```
<div id="songsListPage" data-role="page">

    <div id="alphabets" > 
        <a href="#"  >#</a>
                    <a href="#" >A</a>
                    <a href="#"  >B</a>
                    <a href="#"  >C</a>
                    <a href="#"  >D</a>
                    <a href="#"  >E</a>
                    <a href="#"  >F</a>
                    <a href="#"  >G</a>
                    <a href="#"  >H</a>
                    <a href="#"  >I</a>
                    <a href="#"  >J</a>
                    <a href="#"  >K</a>
                    <a href="#"  >L</a>
                    <a href="#"  >M</a>
    </div>

<div id="songs_list" data-role="content"> <!-- this should not scroll, but it is and showing white background on right side -->

        <ul id="songsList" data-role="listview" data-theme="a"></ul> <!-- list is populated dynamically -->     

        <p>This is songs page</p>

        <a href="player.html" id="playerBtn" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-active" ></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

my css

```
#alphabets {
    background:#000000;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 200%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#alphabets a{ color: #ffffff; margin-left: 5px}
```

by giving "width: 200%" and "overflow-x: auto" i'm getting horizontal scroll but the problem is my rest of the screen is also scrolling horizontally so is there is any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Such bloated code. I actually find that tables work better rather than an LI and DIV list.. I edited this for jSFiddle too. http://jsfiddle.net/CXAWE/

Comment: thanks @TheBlackBenzKid it worked i changed ui and div to tr and table respectively and changing width to 100%. I forget to mention in question that overflow property was working fine in desktop browser but it is not working in phone (android) browser but it is working with table tag. thanks again

Comment: I added my code as answer. Hope you can delete yours and accept mine?

Answer (score 1):

## Old Answer

The New HTML

```
<div id="songsListPage" data-role="page">
<table id="alphabets"> <!-- change "div" tag to "table" tag -->
    <tr>
    <td href="#">#</td> <!-- and "a" to "td" tag -->
    <td href="#">A</td>
    <td href="#">B</td>
    <td href="#">C</td>
    <td href="#">D</td>
    <td href="#">E</td>
    <td href="#">F</td>
    <td href="#">G</td>
    <td href="#">H</td>
    <td href="#">I</td>
    <td href="#">J</td>
    <td href="#">K</td>
    <td href="#">L</td>
    <td href="#">M</td>
    <td href="#">N</td>
    <td href="#">O</td>
    <td href="#">P</td>
    <td href="#">Q</td>
    <td href="#">R</td>
    <td href="#">S</td>
    <td href="#">T</td>
    <td href="#">U</td>
    <td href="#">V</td>
    <td href="#">W</td>
    <td href="#">X</td>
    <td href="#">Y</td>
    <td href="#">Z</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="songs_list" data-role="content">

<ul id="songsList" data-role="listview" data-theme="a"></ul>
<!-- list is populated dynamically -->     
<p>This is songs page</p>
<a href="player.html" id="playerBtn" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-active" ></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS

```
#alphabets {
    background:#000000;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: auto;  <!-- changed width from 200% to auto -->
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#alphabets td{ color: #ffffff; font-size: large; 
margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;} 
<!-- rest of the changes in css are for proper view (UI) like height: auto; padding-left: 5px; (in td) etc -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CXAWE/ (for those who do not want a TABLE TR TD solution)

This will work perfectly in phone (android) browser. The Table TR works better for mobiles - it will and always has and continue to do so. I always use a TABLE for guaranteed results especially in this case.

## Updated New Answer

HTML for any mobile solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML5 Alternative to Mobile WAP and iPad/iPhone etc</title>
<!-- Mobile Web App Acceleration - Powered by WordCompress.net //-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all, handheld" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="b">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
#b {
    margin: 1px;
}
#content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Notice `viewport` width is `device-width` and also notice that the body, has no width, and neither does the content. You can now guarantee that all phones will display 100%. You can change the `overflow` to `y` or `x` too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TheBlackBenzKid but today i tested it on phone it is not working, it is working perfectly on android emulator but not on phone. what to do any hint ?

Comment: Have you tried 100% for the width and same? Also post your full HTML5 - it could be your viewport code or lack of.

Comment: you can find all files html, css and javascript [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pv6RE/)

Comment: Updated my code. It is was the view port and notice my new headers. See answer above.